# Change label Color TextInput react native paper onFocus

Tags: react-native, label, react-native-paper

how to change the label color for textInput when it is focused. I am using react-native-paper by default it is violet in color is there any prop like labelColor to do the same
The label color of TextInput needs to be changed when the textInput is clicked to edit. PLease see the following code for details

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Text, TextInput, Card, Button } from 'react-native-paper'

class login extends Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }
    handleEmail = (text) => {
        this.setState({email: text})
    }
    handlePassword = (text) => {
        this.setState({password: text})
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View style = {styles.container}>
            <View style = {styles.part1}/>
            <View style = {styles.part2}/>
            <View style = {styles.CardContainer}>
            <Card style = {styles.card1}>
                <Card.Title title = "LOGIN" titleStyle = {{alignSelf: 'center',color: '#0080ff'}}/>
                <Card.Content> 
                <TextInput style = {styles.input}
                    underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
                    label = "Email"
                    autoCapitalize = "none"
                    onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}/>

                <TextInput style = {styles.input}
                    underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
                    label = "Password"
                    autoCapitalize = "none"
                    onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}/>
                </Card.Content>
                <Card.Actions>
                  <View  style = {styles.container2}>
                <Button mode = "contained" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')} style = {styles.btn}>
                    LOG IN
                </Button>
                  <Button mode = "text" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')} style = {styles.btn1}>
                  <Text style = {{color: "#0080ff"}}>New User? Register</Text>
               </Button>
               </View>
                </Card.Actions>
            </Card>
            </View>
         </View>
        );      
    }
}

export default login

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
   },
   CardContainer: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      position: 'absolute',
         width: '100%',
         height: '100%',
         justifyContent: 'center',
         paddingHorizontal: 20
   },
   card1: {
      width: '100%',
        borderRadius: 8
   },
   part1: {
      flex: 1.2,
      backgroundColor: '#0080ff',
   },
   part2: {
      flex: 2,
      backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
   },
   input: {
      fontSize: 20,
      paddingVertical: 0,
      paddingHorizontal: 0,
        margin: 15,
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
   },
   btn: {
      width: '75%',
      color: '#0080ff',
      borderRadius: 25,
      backgroundColor: "#0080ff",
      marginTop: 20,
        marginLeft: '12.5%'
   },
   container2: {
         flex: 1,
         flexDirection: 'column',
         justifyContent: 'space-between'
   },
   btn1: {
         color: '#0080ff',
         marginTop: 20
   }
})
```

Comment: Should add some code with the question.

Comment: yeah thanks bro for recomending  please help with the same

Answer (score 5):

You can add theme prop to Textinput
eg:

```js
<TextInput
  label="Phone number"
  theme={{colors: {primary: 'red'}}}
/>
```

Comment: This will change the color of the underline as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can add "theme" prop to TextInput to set color of Label when focus

**Try this**

```
<TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          label="Email"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={this.handleEmail}
          theme={{colors: {primary: 'red'}}}
        />
```

if you do not want to add theme prop for each textinput component you can set the default theme

**Try this**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {
  TextInput,
  DefaultTheme,
  Provider as PaperProvider,
} from 'react-native-paper';

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: 'red',
  },
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
    name: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 60}}>
        <TextInput
          label="Email"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
        />
        <TextInput
          label="Name"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

**Note : App should be your main root component if you want to set for complete app**

App Demo

[image]

Comment: The placeholder animation you create it from scratch or it's built-in in RN-paper?

Comment: @Oliver D , It is built in in RN-paper