# Change labels text color when input is active

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am trying to accomplish what I have posted below, I have found some things using onChange and onChangeText but no good documentation. Could someone post a good article or an explanation below! Thank you for any insight at all!

[image]

```
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#FF0000'};}
  
  
        {/* Email Input */}
      <Container style = {styles.emailInput}>
        
        <Form>
          <Item floatingLabel style={{color:this.state.color1}} >
          onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
          onClick={() => this.setState({color1: '##F7018D'})}
          onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
           <Label>
           Email Address</Label>
           <Input
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
 
            />
         </Item>
       </Form>
      </Container>

 emailInput: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#1E2028',
    width: 350,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 225,
    left: 3

  }
```

Comment: Here is a similar question which you're looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786281/change-label-color-textinput-react-native-paper-onfocus

Comment: This uses react-native-paper I would rather not have to use that unless I need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the following inside the Input

```
onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#0000FF'})}
  onClick={() => this.setState({color1: '#0000FF'})}
  onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#FF0000'})}
```

and then in your style section, use the "this.state.color1" as your text color.

In this way, when the input box is on focus, the textcolor will be changed to blue, and when the user clicks else where, it will become red in color

To give you an example, please try the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      color1: '#FF0000'};}

    

  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <TextInput
 
    style={{color:this.state.color1 , borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#DD0000',}}
placeholder="Type something"
  onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#0000FF'})}
  onClick={() => this.setState({color1: '#0000FF'})}
  onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#FF0000'})}


        />

<TextInput value="TEST2"/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 60,
  },


  
});
```

you may visit this link to see too:
https://snack.expo.io/71LpKDzvS

Additional information

for your revised codes, please change

```
 <Item floatingLabel style={{color:this.state.color1}} >
          onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
          onClick={() => this.setState({color1: '##F7018D'})}
          onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
           <Label>
           Email Address</Label>
           <Input
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
 
            />
```

to

```
 <Item floatingLabel  >
           <Label style={{color:this.state.color1}}>
           Email Address</Label>
           <Input
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onFocus={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}
          onClick={() => this.setState({color1: '##F7018D'})}
          onBlur={() => this.setState({color1: '#A2A2A2'})}

 
            />
```

to see the effect.

Comment: So I pasted the code you gave me inside the input and in my style section I wrote 
```
color: 'this.state.color1'
```

Is that correct? Do I need to import something?

Comment: This gets the job done kinda... I need my label to change color, not the actual input. I have tried playing around with it in my label and my Item, but cant quite get anything going. I feel like you have given be enough information! I am close I can feel it.

Comment: I updated my attempt at the slight change, I cant figure it out though, Mind looking at my updated code and helping?

Comment: please see the "additional information" part and try. Thanks

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!! I really appreciate your time.